# How to train tensorflow network with 0D (scalar) labels?

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a task, where I'd like to count things on an image. I have labels for the images, which are integer values, but I have never seen such kind of tutorial yet. All the examples are cases, where the final output of the tf network, and the labels are 1D vector objects (one-hot vectors usually). Can you help me with a python code/tutorial/paper, where the labels are scalars?

Comment: You can make the output of your network any shape. Nobody prevents you from making it a single int. That said, networks train better with one-hot, so if you have an upper limit on how many interesting features your images might possibly have, you would still be better off with one-hot..

Comment: So lets say I can have a total of 6 objects, then If I have 1, my label would be [0,1,0,0,0,0,0], if I have 6, then my label would be [0,0,0,0,0,0,1] ?

Comment: Yes. As you imagine, this only works if you know for sure the maximum number of objects an image can have, since your output size is fixed. So if you know you cannot possibly have more than a 100 objects, you can set your output to be a 101 units and one_hot encode it. TensorFlow has a native op to encode, called tf.one_hot() you can look it up in the docs. You can use it to encode your training labels.

Comment: If I would use fixed size hot vectors, then would'nt I cheat the deep network, becouse the difference between 1 object and 6 objects is the same as the difference between 1 object and 2 objects? With scalar label this problem does not exist. Is my concern justifiable here?

Comment: Generally, a classifier doesn't and most likely shouldn't care about relationships between classes. When you have, for example, 6 objects in the picture the classifier is trying to recognize it as 6, if it doesn't, it doesn't matter if it comes up with 5 or 20, it is still wrong. But for reasons that involve some multivariate calculus and a lot of mathy headache, training classifiers this way tends to work better. You can make your output a single unit and train that way, it is not in any way impossible, but it might be less efficient in terms of resulting accuracy and training time.